# Border around imageview isn't drawn properly

Tags: android, imageview

I'm trying to add border around an ImageView.
I use the following drawable XML:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
   <solid android:color="#ffffffff" />
   <padding android:left="3dp" android:right="3dp" android:top="3dp" android:bottom="3dp"/>
   <stroke android:width="3dip" android:color="#4fa5d5"/>
</shape>
```

But the border appears not fully adjacent to image:
[image]

Anyone knows how to make the border stick to the image?

Thanks

Comment: use a 9-patch image instead.

Comment: would it be ok to stretch the image?

Comment: 9 patch as a border? got an example? @SarthakMittal - no...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The drawn padding appears around ImageView not around your image.

Try to use this on your imageView:

```
imgCelebrity.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
```

If it doesn't work try with 9-patch image.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify correct `ScaleType` in your `ImageView` so that image inside it fill entire view. You can do this through XML `android:scaleType`. Try setting `android:scaleType="FIT_CENTER"`.